# What is the equivalent of Hobbs and Tach in a Jet or Turbine Aircraft?

Tags: jet-engine, turbine

As a piston pilot I am only familiar with tracking hours for my pilot log book and maintenance log book using the Hobbs and Tach times.  Can someone tell me what the equivalent is for a Turbine and for a Jet?

Comment: We used clock time to track Metroliners and hobbs to track a Turbo Commander.  I think hobbs is acceptable if installed.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/31301/62)

Comment: Any installed time tracking system will be acceptable for logging maintenance times. Under FAA regulations, mechanical or electrical time tracking systems in aircraft generally do not keep track of "flight time" which is what is to be logged or kept track of. See 14 CFR 1.1 In the turbine I fly we log time based on block to block time, which is the same as FAA defined flight time in our case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all of our jets, we have two hobbs meters. One is active from left engine start and the other goes active when the weight of the aircraft leaves the wheels. Neither of these are used for logging our flight time. We do that "chock-to-chock", ie as soon as the chocks are pulled and we start moving to when the chocks are put back in the wheels.

The regs say you can log flight time from when "the aircraft moves under it's own power for the purpose of flight":

> Flight time means:
>   (1) Pilot time that commences when an aircraft moves under its own power for the purpose of flight and ends when the aircraft comes to rest after landing; or
>   (2) For a glider without self-launch capability, pilot time that commences when the glider is towed for the purpose of flight and ends when the glider comes to rest after landing.

Comment: Which of those measures are used to track total time for maintenance purposes (e.g. phase inspections etc.)?

Comment: We use WOW for all maintenance.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, what does WOW stand for?

Comment: Sorry about that - it stands for Weight on Wheels.